# Getting breadcrumbs to work on taxonomy pages

Tags: drupal-7, breadcrumbs

I have Drupal 7.10 installed with Pathauto, Global Redirect, and Custom Breadcrumbs.

I've assigned a pattern to all my taxonomy term pages (products/browse/vocabulary/term-name). Now, on every term page, I'd like the breadcrumb trail to read something like this:

Home > Products > Vocabulary

I've tried to achieve that with Custom Breadcrumbs, but what I apply to the vocabulary doesn't work on the term page itself, and working at term-level it seems I'd be required to write a manual path for each and every term (<-- major bad idea).

I've also tried overriding the term page with Panels, then using Custom Breadcrumbs to create a trail for that specific panel. The problem here: no available taxonomy tokens to get the vocabulary name.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?